# PATH doesn't change after restart Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, path, homebrew, nvm

I've got stuck with it.

I try to edit path in order to work with mysql from iTerm.

I tried different ways to edit my PATH:

1) typing command in terminal `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`

2) edit .bash_profile

3) edit .bashrc

Everything works pretty well until I restart my Mac.

Here is what my constant PATH looks like 
`echo $PATH
/Users/lyubakov/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: what says : **echo $SHELL**

Comment: → echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

Answer (score 1):

On MAC OS X there is no use of ~/.bash_profile but ~/.bashrc.

make sure you hadn't override PATH in other places that run after the line you added.

You didn't give us enough information of your system configuration... such as the bashrc, bash_profile of the user.

Comment: here is ~/.bashrc
`export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

SSH_ENV=/Users/lyubakov/.ssh/environment

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi`

Comment: what else i should paste here?

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Lyubakov - Any Question ? If you use the **zsh** they never reads the profiles from the **bash**. 
you must change the zsh profiles like **.zshrc**

at the end of **man zsh** is a list of files where you can do your changes